# Android: Youtube API playlist

Tags: java, android, eclipse, youtube, youtube-api

I've been doing an apps that using YouTube API in my project. I had tab that represent 3 tabs. First channel tab, second top video and finally fav video. I want to use the standalone YouTube but somehow it cannot display the video for each tab. So, i test the code in the top tab first and it give this error  "ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE". Please help me. Thanks :)

```
/import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.brickred.socialshare.YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity;
//import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
//import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;


public class Top extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

        public static final String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLC7961A4662BB1042";
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.top);

            YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
            youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEV_KEY, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {
          if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadPlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID);
          }
        }

        @Override
        protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
          return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        }
}
```

Comment: This quetion is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673644/1726308). I think your problem is the same.