# Android Youtube Player Api - ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the new api youtube. I followed the examples provided, but I get the error: ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE

The "API key" that I'm using is correct (since it works correctly in the google demos).

Imports:

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
```

Classe definition:

```
public class Track extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

     private YouTubePlayerView ytpv;
     private YouTubePlayer ytp;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          ...

          ytpv = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
          ytpv.initialize("my_api_key_correctly_created", this); 
     }

     public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization Fail" + arg1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }


     public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {
          ytp = arg1;
          Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization  Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          if(ytp !=null)
          {
               ytp.loadVideo("ZvvgDC_MNqI");
          }
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you, and sorry my english:)

Comment: ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE is the retrived string from arg1.toString() in onInitializationFailure method.

Comment: do you mean API key= developer key

Comment: Do you have internet permission?

Comment: Yes i have internet permission. API key was generated from my debug.keystore on google apis (https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:106804967022:access), and work fine on google youtube player demos

Comment: Could you please share the logcat output during the call to `initialize()`?

Comment: I have not output. The result of initialize() its the error: `ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to start the 'Track' Activity as part of an ActivityGroup/TabActivity inside a TabHost?  If so, unfortunately the YouTubePlayerView or YouTubePlayerFragment can't be initialized inside an ActivityGroup.  Since the ActivityGroup is now deprecated, the only suggestion I can give is to use Fragments instead.

Comment: You right. I use ActivityGroup/TabActivity... But now I can not change the app to not use ActivityGroup ... Do not hesitate another solution?  Alternatively, what changes to stop using ActivityGroup? And thank you for your answer, realy helps me :)