# Tabs which switch between views in Android

Tags: tabs, android

what I'm trying to do should be easy yet I found myself stuck. I need to have 3 tabs in an android activity. Each tab should switch between activities and not views. I've implemented  this with tabActivity which despite being deprecated, it did the job. But then I realized that the YoutubePlayerView couldn't be initialized as shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604280/android-youtube-player-api-error-connecting-to-service). Also I don't want my tabs to be on my ActionBar. So my question is how can I have tabs in an activity which will switch between Activities?

Comment: you can use fragments instead of Activities.

Comment: If i use fragments shouldn't I declare the layout of each fragment to the tabhost activity?

Answer (score 0):

`TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);`

```
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec; View tabView;


tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");       
    tabView = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Tab 1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, YourActivity1.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tabView = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Tab 2");
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, YourActivity2.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");
    tabView = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Tab 3");
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, YourActivity3.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

When you click a tab for the first time, the corresponding Activity will start, and will keep running even if you switch to another tab (i.e. will not pause). If you switch back to previous tab, its `onResume` is not going to be invoked

Comment: @libathos yes, it's in TabActivity

Comment: I've implemented it this way, if it's done in such a way, I can't initialize the YoutubePlayerView

Comment: @libathos I guess the problem is in that PlayerView then, not in Tabs :) The activity is supposed to start successfully

Comment: The problem lies in that PlayerView because TabActivity is deprecated

Comment: I don't really think that it's because of TabActivity being deprecated, but if you want you may try using `FragmentActivity` instead, like it was suggested by the user above

Comment: It is because of that.I've posted a link which explains why that is